# Are there any Mac text editors with a built-in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editors

I was wondering if there exists a plain text editor that has one built-in terminal. I think Coda does it, but too much for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Emacs is installed on Mac OS X by default.  It has a terminal built in that works nicely.

Comment: If the OP is already used to mac style shortcuts I recommend Aquamacs as it's just Emacs with added keybindings. Personally I'm already used to Emacs so I stick with the original.

Comment: I tend to recommend the original to everybody, because that way it works the same on any system in front of which they sit down.

Comment: As do I but some ppl that are just really used to other editors and are not really going to use it often I recommend Aquamacs as it is quite a nice port. Personally the original is the only one for me.

Answer (score 3):

Coda is pretty web dev focused, so if that's "too much" it might help to describe exactly what you're planning on using the terminal for.

Emacs has multiple shell modes, some of which behave more like editors and some more like terminals. BBEdit has shell worksheets which are even more like editors than Emacs' modes; [Eddie](http://www.el34.com/) also has 
shell worksheets (both are modeled after a feature in MPW, Apple's IDE for classic Mac OS).

Comment: Looking at the link for Eddie really takes me back, but in the end I'm an emacs guy.

Comment: Me too, I just included it for completeness. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)

<kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> <kbd>sh</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

[Kate Editor](http://kate-editor.org/)  is pretty good available in windows and linux i think. I used it for C and shell projects. can be used for plenty other.

Comment: Typically avoid posting answers which are just product recommendations. This question was essentially asking for recommendations - which is typically not acceptable here. Just so you know.